# How to trigger a child component event in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

Given the following, how do I trigger an event for the Foo component in componentDidMount:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Foo from 'Foo';

export default class Bar extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    // How to trigger the onChange event for this.refs.foo
  }

  render() {

    const onFooChanged= (resultFromFoo) => {
        // do stuff
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Foo ref="foo" onChange={onFooChanged} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You could call `this.props.onChange` from `componentDidMount` in Foo instead of in Bar? Or just call your `onChange` function from componentDidMount.  For this you'd need to move `onChange` out from the render function. Typically event handlers should not be defined there anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inject the onChange function as a prop, you simply can access the prop and call it.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.foo.props.onChange()
  }
```

I added a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/27193/

Comment: How do I inject the onChange function as a prop? this.refs.foo.props is currently undefined.

Comment: You already inject the handler as a prop.  <Foo ref="foo" onChange={onFooChanged} /> So it should be accessible. That is strange

Comment: My fault. I had a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just move the `onChange` function out of the `render` method and call it directly.  Since the method is on the `Bar` class, no need to go through the `Foo` component to call it.

```
export default class Bar extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    // How to trigger the onChange event for this.refs.foo
    this.onChange();
  }

  onChange() {
    // do stuff
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Foo ref="foo" onChange={this.onChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: On change is also defined in Foo as a prop and that needs to run before the onChange in Bar. I've edited the question to make this clearer.